# How to bind to static property programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How to bind to static property programmatically? What can I use in C# to make

```
{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyClass.StaticProperty}}
```

**Update:** is it possible to do OneWayToSource binding? I understand that TwoWay is not possible because there are no update events on static objects (at least in .NET 4). I cannot instantiate object because it is static.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***OneWay binding***

Let's assume that you have class `Country` with static property `Name`.

```
public class Country
{
  public static string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And now you want binding property `Name` to `TextProperty` of `TextBlock`.

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = Country.Name;
this.tbCountry.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

***Update: TwoWay binding***

`Country` class looks like this:

```
public static class Country
    {
        private static string _name;

        public static string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                Console.WriteLine(value); /* test */
            }
        }
    }
```

And now we want binding this property `Name` to `TextBox`, so:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = typeof(Country);
binding.Path = new PropertyPath(typeof(Country).GetProperty("Name"));
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
this.tbCountry.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

If you want update target you must use `BindingExpression` and function `UpdateTarget`:

```
Country.Name = "Poland";

BindingExpression be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this.tbCountry, TextBox.TextProperty);
be.UpdateTarget();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always write a non-static class to provide access to the static one.

Static class:

```
namespace SO.Weston.WpfStaticPropertyBinding
{
    public static class TheStaticClass
    {
        public static string TheStaticProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Non-static class to provide access to static properties.

```
namespace SO.Weston.WpfStaticPropertyBinding
{
    public sealed class StaticAccessClass
    {
        public string TheStaticProperty
        {
            get { return TheStaticClass.TheStaticProperty; }
        }
    }
}
```

Binding is then simple:

```
<Window x:Class="SO.Weston.WpfStaticPropertyBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO.Weston.WpfStaticPropertyBinding"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:StaticAccessClass x:Key="StaticAccessClassRes"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TheStaticProperty, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=StaticAccessClassRes}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```