# bind to and update a static property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, static

I searched Google for a solution but I couldn't apply what I've found with my problem here, so I have a static class with static properties, I wish to bind a ListView static property to an ObservableCollection property, this is done but now I want to notify the ListView with changes happened in the ObservableCollection

```
 public static class Global
{
   public static ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,object>>> operations;
   ObservableCollection<String> names = new ObservableCollection<string>();
   public static ObservableCollection<String> _Operations
   {
       get
       {               

           for (int i = 0; i < Global.operations.Count; i++)
           {
               if (Global.operations.Count != 0)
               {
                   names.Add(Global.operations[i].Keys.First().ToString());
               }
           }
           return names;
       }
       set
       {
           if (_Operations != value)
           {
               _Operations = value;
           }
       }

   }

}
```

then the XAML

```
<ListView Name="list"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static s:Global._Operations}}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"  />
                    <Button Content="Delete" Click="Button_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

this is the code that deletes,I'm sure it adds and deletes because I can see the "Operation" being added or deleted effect immediately

```
var item = ((Button)sender).DataContext;
        var itemIndex = list.Items.IndexOf(item);
        Global.operations.RemoveAt(itemIndex);
        list.Items.Refresh();
```

This binds and display, obviously I need to update the ListView when I delete/add items to my static ObservableCollection. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: you should check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549774/how-to-bind-to-static-property-programmatically

Comment: What about making Global a singleton that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @Andy This "singleton" part I couldn't apply on my case here , I'm a newbie

Comment: @Musaab I added an answer with how to use a singleton. I'm not sure if the code you posted compiles - seems like there might be some errors in the _Operations property, not sure though.

Comment: @Musaab can you show your code that adds and deletes.

Comment: The problem might be that you're returning a new `ObservableCollection` each time the `_Operations` property is retrieved. Can you rewrite it so that it always returns the same instance?

Comment: I removed the initialization from the "get" to somewhere else on the class, still the same result

Comment: I think you need an ObservableDictionary not an ObservableCollection.  Are you really intending each element in the ObservableCollection to be a dictionary where the key is a string and the value a dictionary? Also, have you tried to call the set method on the _Operations property.  I think a stack overflow will result.

Comment: Well, I need the value to be a dictionary because there I need to save an operation name,and a parameters list with string as a parameter name and and object for it's value, I can't understand the latter part of your comment @grantnz

Comment: Your set method on _Operations executes _Operations = value; which will cause the set method on _Operations to be called (i.e. it will call itself).  This will happen repeated until the stack is full (i.e. until a stack overflow occurs).  BTW, you can get the code for an ObservableDictionary from http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx

Comment: How about ObservableDictionary<string,Dictionary<string,object>>>.  The string would be the operation name and the Dictionary the parameter names and their values.

Comment: I don't have any errors or exceptions, it just doesn't update, and when I close the window and reopen it; I have my desired result,but of course I want that update to be LIVE,I may try the ObservableDictionary as the last attempt,but for now I don't think using the obseravableCollection is the problem.

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code?  The problem with the code as written is that you never change the _Operations observablecollection as a new collection is provided whenever the get method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You could change `Global` to be a singleton and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Something like this:

```
public class Global : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static Global _instance = new Global();
    public static Global Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    private ObservableCollection<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>> operations = new ObservableCollection<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> _Operations
    {
        get
        {
            // ...
        }
        set
        {
            // ...
            OnPropertyChanged("_Operations");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName);
    }
}
```

You would set up in the binding like this:

```
<ListView Name="list" DataContext="{x:Static Global.Instance}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_Operations}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"  />
                <Button Content="Delete" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @Musaab I think I misread your post - I thought the problem was with changing the `ObservableCollection`, not with adding/removing items.

Answer (score 0):

With the way your code is setup, the only way I could think of to force a refresh is to set the ItemsSource to null and then set ItemsSource back

You are changing operations but not _Operations to which your listview is bound to that is the problem. Use the below code and it should work.

```
    var item = ((Button)sender).DataContext;
    var itemIndex = list.Items.IndexOf(item);
    Global.operations.RemoveAt(itemIndex);
    list.ItemsSource = null;
    list.ItemsSource = Global._Operations;
```

Comment: yeah but that automatically changes _Operations too , it give outOfRangeException, which is logical because I'm testing with one operation and it is removed by Global.operations.RemoveAt(itemIndex);

Comment: NullReferenceException, please remember that I want to update this via the data-binding

Comment: @Musaab updated, this should work for sure. Else, I have no further clues.

Comment: well this somehow reproduced the problem, to reference Global._Operations, _Operations has to be static,but then if we make it static it won't be able then to notify with the change

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your Global class with the following, additions/deletions made on the operation object will be propagated to _names and the binding will work correctly.

Additional code would be required if you need to assign to Global.operation (e.g would need to subscribe to the new collections CollectionChanged event) but presumably you can modify your existing code to simply add/remove from Global.operation.

```
public static class Global
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>> operations = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>();

    static ObservableCollection<String> names = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public static ObservableCollection<String> _Operations
    {
        get
        {               
            return names;
        }
    }

    static Global()
    {
        operations.CollectionChanged += operations_CollectionChanged;
    }

    static void operations_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> value in e.OldItems)
            {
                _Operations.Remove(value.Keys.First().ToString( ));
            }
        }
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> value in e.NewItems)
            {
                _Operations.Add(value.Keys.First().ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```