# Change/use StaticResource across app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I want to change skin color, so did this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="AppColor">#FFFFFF</Color>
</Application.Resources>
```

and then used it across the app for example:

```
<...... BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppColor}" ... />
```

it works fine. but when I try to change it I face some problems.

```
Application.Current.Resources["AppColor"] = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 255);
```

I get a not implemented error. when I try remove it and add a new one:

```
Application.Current.Resources.Remove("AppColor");
var color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 255);
Application.Current.Resources.Add("AppColor", color);
```

I get a xaml error, just whereever I've used that static value.

How can I use a color and change it?

Comment: that didn't work too!

Comment: I think the fundamental problem is that static resources shouldn't change in run-time. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549774/how-to-bind-to-static-property-programmatically) might give you a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `SolidColorBrush` in resources

Example define `SolidColorBrush`, with `x:Name="AppBrush"` in App.xaml resources

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBrush" Color="#FF7DC959"/>
```

If your binding Target is Color then it will be like this

```
<....BackgroundColor="{Binding Color,Source={StaticResource AppBrush}}">
```

And if your binding target is SolidColorBrush it will be like this

```
<....BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBrush}">
```

Then you can change Color property in code

```
SolidColorBrush brush = (SolidColorBrush)App.Current.Resources["AppBrush"];
brush.Color = Colors.DarkGray;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `DynamicResource` instead of a `StaticResource` should fix this:

```xml
<...... BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource AppColor}" />
```

```cs
Application.Current.Resources["AppColor"] = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 255);
```